# Prove: for any $A\subset E$, measurable, $lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}fn = \int_{A}f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f, f_{n}$ be nonnegative functions in $L(E)$ and $f_{n}\to f$ a.e.$lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}f_{n} = \int_{E}f$

Prove: for any $A\subset E$, measurable, $lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}fn = \int_{A}f$

I am trying to prove this by proving $"\le" and"\ge"$,

$"\le"$: Since $A\subset E$,  $\int_{E}f_{n}\le\int_{E}f_{n+1}\le...\le\int_{A}f_{k}\le\int_{A}f_{k+1}\le\int_{A}f\le...\le\int_{E}f$

So,$lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}f_{n}\le\int_{A}f$

But I have no idea how to prove $"\ge"$,any hint? And is my prove of $"\le"$ correct?

Comment: Fatou's lemma. Look at $A$ and at $E\setminus A$.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713892/from-the-whole-space-to-sunsets-how-to-prove-this-integral-limit It's important to note that this may be false if $\int_Ef=\infty$.

Comment: @carmichael561 I think we have this property :If f is integrable, than f is finite, isn't it?

Comment: If $f$ is integrable then everything works out fine. See the first answer to the question I linked.

Comment: @carmichael561 I have a problem, do we need to show $\int_{E^c} f\,d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E^c} f_n\,d\mu$?

Comment: That's just Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @carmichael561   OH,Because E measurable, so $E^c$ is also measurable

Comment: @carmichael561 Thank you! I got it!